# How do inline functions resolve multiple function definitions?

Tags: c++, inline

I was watching the C++ series made by The Cherno and in one of the videos, he mentions that if there is a function Log() that is defined in a header file and included in multiple cpp files, this will cause there to be a linker error because the function is effectively being defined in each of those cpp files (since a header file is just copied and pasted by #include). He says that there are two ways to resolve this: make the function static or inline. I understand the logic behind static: it makes it visible only to the current translation unit. However, I still don't understand how inline resolves this issue. Suppose we have:

**Log.h**

```
#include <iostream>

inline void LOG(const char* msg)
{
    std::cout << msg << std::endl;
}
```

**Log.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Log.h"
void print()
{
    LOG("Hello");
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>    
#include "Log.h"
void print();

int main()
{
    LOG("hello");
    print();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

In this case, I would assume that when Log.cpp and Main.cpp include "Log.h", the Log function is pasted into both files (meaning there are now 2 inline Log functions in the project - one in Main.cpp and other in Log.cpp). Now when the Log function is called, how does the compiler know which Log function to replace the code with (I say replace because the functions are inline so it would replace the Log() call with the body of the function)? It could be the one in Log.cpp or Main.cpp. Since the function is inline and not static, both of them should be globally visible.

Comment: A linker doesn't know which function to pick, it will make some unspecified choice. `inline` doesn't mean inlining. These are different concepts. Some people say `inline` is a hint for inlining.

Comment: @Evg Can you explain this a bit more? https://www.cplusplus.com/articles/2LywvCM9/ It says here that inline is "compiler can replace those function definition wherever those are being called". And by unspecified choice, do you mean it will call any of the functions randomly?

Comment: 1) A compiler can replace a function call with its body even if a function is not marked as `inline`. Some people say that `inline` is a hint to a compiler to make such a replacement more probable. 2) The primary use of `inline` is to tell a *linker* that a function can be defined in several compilation units. A linker will pick just one definition and put it into a binary. All non-inlined calls will invoke that function. It is not specified, which one will be picked, but it doesn't matter - all copies should have the same body anyway (violating this condition is UB).

Comment: I am sorry. I am still a bit confused about your second point. Can you tell me where I can read more about this? Everywhere I look I find the "replaces body of function " definition

Comment: One reason I am confused is, I thought inlining happens during compilation right? So if the compiler chooses to replace the call with the body, how does it know which one? Second, you said that a linker randomly chooses one and places it in the binary. Does this mean that if the compiler chooses it to be non inclined, all calls to this will be invoked? And if it IS inclined, it will be replaced by call?

Comment: There are many good questions and answers here about `inline` and inlining. Just bear in mind that `inline` and inlining are distinct concepts when you read them. You'll find many answers that explain this difference further.

Comment: A compiler or a linker doesn't have to make a specific choice because you as a programmer have to ensure that all bodies are identical. It will make some choice according to an internal algorithm, but we don't care what that choice will be. If a function is inlined by a compiler, a linker won't need to do anything with that function call - there will be no function call at all. Also note that cpp files are compiled one by one, so most likely a compiler will see just one definition of an inline function and won't have any choice at all if it decides to inline it